# Parsing pre tag line by line using python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, pre

I have a HTML file that contains data in pre tags. I want to parse the data in pre tags line by line and perform sorting based on timestamp in each line.How can i do that using python.

```
<pre>**Date Time DataFeed**
10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep
.......
.......</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import bs4

In [2]: text = '''<pre>**Date Time DataFeed**
   ...: 10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep
   ...: 10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep
   ...: 10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep
   ...: 10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep</pre>'''

In [3]: soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

In [4]: soup.pre.get_text()
Out[4]: '**Date Time DataFeed**\n10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep\n10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep\n10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep\n10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep'
In [6]: soup.pre.get_text().splitlines()
Out[6]: 
['**Date Time DataFeed**',
 '10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep',
 '10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep',
 '10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep',
 '10/01/1994 10:00:00 Go_to_sleep']
```

In bs4, the html code with line break are converted to `\n`, you can use `splitlines()` to split it into list.

Comment: it works but the problem is that the file is really large and it takes a lot of time to process it and display. Is there any faster method